# Custom callback function attribute android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

As android defines attributes inside the attrs files and I have seen that Button has attribute onClick listed. Is there a way to create custom attributes referencing functions as so and how does on go about implementing it.

```xml
<Button
  ...
  android:onClick="onClickFunction"/>
```

What I want to have

```xml
<CustomView
   ...
   android:onItemClick="onItemClicked"/>
```

attrs.xml

```xml
<attr name="onItemClick" format="string"/>
```

How does one create attach this function as a listener to the view?

Comment: Yes, to solve this problem you can create custom views with custom attributes from XML.  The custom view is a class that extends from View (or ViewGroup, but ViewGroup it is a view too).

Comment: @Breimer, check this official android developer guidelines to create custom properties for custom view -- https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view I hope this will guide you on all the things you need to achieve it.